# How to convert mf4 files into mat files using asammdf?

Tags: asammdf

I am knew to this topic and building a GUI for file conversion from mf4 to mat.
Using the mdfreader already but need to extend it with asammdf to have an option.

Answer (score 0):

The asammdf GUI already provides this functionality